# Polymer not working as expected in Firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, polymer, web-component

I am trying to incorporate Polymer with Rails 4 using [the polymer-rails](https://github.com/alchapone/polymer-rails) and [polymer-paper-rails](https://github.com/alchapone/polymer-paper-rails) Gems.

I seem to be having a lot of problems getting any elements to display in Firefox. After looking around and quite a lot of searching on Google, I have come to the conclusion that it must be an issue with my `platfom.js` file.

I have followed the instructions for installing both the aforementioned gems to the letter and really don't know what I'm doing wrong. The paper elements work perfectly in Google Chrome.

In my Firefox dev console I see the Message

> "platform.js is not the first script on the page. See
>   http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/platform.html#setup for
>   details." platform.js:12".

This is what my application.js file looks like:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require elements/ripple
//= require forms/select

$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });
```

The  section of my HTML looks like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "foundation-rails" %></title>

    <%= javascript_include_tag 'polymer/platform' %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
    <%= html_import_tag 'application'%>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Comment: Check the dev console in Firefox - what errors are you seeing?

Comment: Your conclusion is likely correct. The most likely issue causing things to work in Chrome but not other browsers is that polymer.js isn't being included in your page. Without further information though it's hard for us to debug this with you. Can you inspect the javascript that is being served, looking for Platform?

Comment: @Nevir, I have updated the post with code and the console message. I think that you guys are onto something. I have changed the order of require statements in the js file but that didn't seem to work

Comment: What's your layout (or page template) look like? platform.js does some pretty intrusive things to ensure that everything is all polyfilled properly. Make sure that you're not including any other scripts ahead of it.

Comment: You might want to try just adding a `<%= javascript_include_tag 'polymer/platform' %>` at the top of your `head` rather than putting it in your sprockets bundle (not ideal, but might help diagnose at least)

Comment: @Nevir...Thanks I can confirm that the above suggestion removed the initial error message. It has however introduced the following `mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create` Message and the Components are still not rendering correctly

Comment: Looks like a `title` attribute problem. You should either rename an attribute, or download the dev version of `polymer.js`.

Answer (score 0):

The platform.js documentation seem to be outdated (related to 0.5 version of Polymer)

For compatibility on browsers that do not fully support webcomponents you should include

```
//= require webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite
```

After that you should see the components in FF/Safari the same way you see in chrome